# Using Route53 for a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I am not sure if it is the same as [DNS for a subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/414837/dns-for-a-subdomain) and [How to set up multitenant Route53 subdomains with parent domain not on Route53?](https://serverfault.com/questions/456020/how-to-set-up-multitenant-route53-subdomains-with-parent-domain-not-on-route53) but I am trying to set up the following

mydomain.com is managed by a provider like IONOS or Dyn.com which does not provide an API for creating and managing records with Terraform.  Since we have several records there already, I don't want to switch everything to Route53 all at once.

What I want to do is set up such that `tenants.mydomain.com` and `*.tenants.mydomain.com` is managed by Route53 but I only want to manually configure `tenants.mydomain.com` on the existing provider once.

The instructions [How to set up multitenant Route53 subdomains with parent domain not on Route53?](https://serverfault.com/questions/456020/how-to-set-up-multitenant-route53-subdomains-with-parent-domain-not-on-route53) does it for each subdomain.  However, it does not say whether it can handle the sub-subdomains.

(Just trying it out right now, but learning on how to set up Route 53 right now so I am not sure if it would work).

UPDATE: doing the steps for [How to set up multitenant Route53 subdomains with parent domain not on Route53?](https://serverfault.com/questions/456020/how-to-set-up-multitenant-route53-subdomains-with-parent-domain-not-on-route53)  allows me to set up the sub-subdomain records and works well with Terraform